# Decryption/Encryption of String on both SQL and VB.net?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, encryption

I am currently working on a project at work. Have come into a dead end as far as research is concerned. 
I am looking to find a universal encrypt and decrypt for strings on both sql and vb.net. I am aware of TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider and other VB.net encryption. However, those methods only solve my problem on the VB side. The issue I run into now is updating pre-existing data in the database to be encrypted so that I can decrypt on VB side.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Depends on your database. Check its capabilities and then you can see what VB.Net provides.

Comment: When you say "SQL" do you actually mean "SQL Server"? SQL is just a language that basically all databases use for queries and schema definition. There's nothing inherent in SQL that will do the encryption for you. If you do mean SQL Server then it's actually possible to load .NET DLLs to be invoked a stored procedures. What that means is that you could write one set of encryption code in a .NET DLL and then use it in both your application and your database.

Comment: We use Sql Server. I'm not sure I follow how I can execute a .NET dll in a stored procedure.

Comment: you can host .net dll on your sql server. See Assemblies folder in your DB under Programmability. See this [link](https://weblogs.asp.net/farhank/creating-clr-sql-user-defined-function-to-validate-values-using-regular-expression) for how to create CLR user defined function.

Comment: Or just pull the data out in an encrypted form and decrypt in your app? Why do you need to decrypt before you pull it out?

Comment: *Which* SQL Server version? *Why* do you want to encrypt these strings and what do you want to protect against? SQL Server already provides several encryption features. Do you want to prevent people from eavesdropping on the connection? Then use [SSL encryption](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067.aspx). Do you want to encrypt the stored data so it's unreadable if the disk is stolen? Use [Transparent Data Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption-tde).

Comment: Do you want to encrypt specific fields so even DBAs can't read them without authorization? That's covered by [Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine). Check the documentation's [Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/sql-server-encryption) section which explains the various encryption features